# How do I create a Thread Pool with a LinkedBlockingQueue in Java?

Tags: java

How do I create a Thread Pool with a LinkedBlockingQueue in Java?  I am using this to download files from the internet.  I just need the general pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ThreadPoolExecutor` has [various constructors](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#constructor_summary) that take a `BlockingQueue` argument. There are several other parameters, though, and you'll need to pick the ones appropriate for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one demo :

```
public static ExecutorService newLinkedBlockingQueueThreadPool() {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                                  60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                                  new  LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
}
```